# Obtain or verify owner or admin of a fan page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way to verify that the user owns the fan page or get the id of the owner or admin of the fan page?
I tried as well but it did not work, I've read a lot but did not find anything.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'=>'', // replace with your value
    'secret'=>'' // replace with your value
));
$signedRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if( $signedRequest['page']['admin'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

`/me/accounts` with the `manage_pages` permission returns a list of all Pages you manage. That´s how you can check out if the authorized User manages a Page.

In a Page App, it´s possible with the `signed_request` parameter, as you found out. Not sure what "it didn´t work" means, you should debug $signedRequest. Here are the fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request

Of course this only works in a Page App - meaning, in the iframe of an App, on a Facebook Page.

Comment: I could not make it work. Is there a way to list my fan pages?

Comment: /me/accounts is for listing the fan pages you manage. but in your case you only need to use the signed_request parameter, to find out if the user is admin of the page. did you do what i say and debug $signedRequest? "it does not work" is very unspecific.